# PHP only first level of subdirectories into an array

Tags: php

I'm trying to get only the first level of subdirectories into an array.
Does someone know a slimmer and faster way to do this?

```
    $dirs =  new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('myroot', RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dirs, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    $dir_array = array();
    foreach( $files AS $file) 
    {           
        if($files->isDot()) continue;
        if($files->getDepth() > 0) continue;

        if( $files->isDir() )
        {
            $dir_array[] = $file->getFilename();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple as this:

```
$array = glob('myroot/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

To get only the base directory name and not the full path:

```
$array = array_map('basename', glob('myroot/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR));
```

See http://php.net/glob

Comment: yes, absolutely. There are iterators for recursively iterating as you already know.

Comment: ok, but that gives me the full paths rather than an array with only the subdir names like above.

Comment: @Mike: Map the array with `basename`